# Detect whether cell value was actually changed by editing

Tags: vba, excel

`Worksheet_Change` triggers when a cell value is changed (which is what I want), but it also triggers when you enter a cell as if to edit it but don't actually change the cell's value (and this is what I don't want to happen).

Say I want to add shading to cells whose value was changed. So I code this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End Sub
```

Now to test my work:  Change cell A1 and the cell gets highlighted.  That's the desired behaviour. So far so good.  Then, double click B1 but don't change the value there and then click C1.  You'll notice B1 gets highlighted!  And this is not the desired behaviour.

Do I have to go through the methods discussed here of capturing the old value, then compare old to new before highlighting the cell?  I certainly hope there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, you do :). The `Change` event is designed to capture an edit to the cell - not to measure the data from that edit - so a test to compare the results of an edit to the prior state is outside the direct scope of the `Change` event

Comment: @user - you are correct in thinking that this seems odd.  I guess the question which can only be answered by a more specific (and complex) approach such as other responses to similar questions here is: "changed relative to when"? Gimp's suggestion is fine if that's your aim - to track all changes in a specific session.  However, you'd need to use another approach if you wanted to track (eg) multiple changes in a given session.  Worksheet_change just gives you the event as a "hook" - you have to build (unfortunately sometimes a lot) on top of that to match your specific needs.

Comment: Have you considered using the `Track Changes` feature?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest automatically maintaining a "mirror copy" of your sheet, in another sheet, for comparison with the changed cell's value.

@brettdj and @JohnLBevan essentially propose doing the same thing, but they store cell values in comments or a dictionary, respectively (and +1 for those ideas indeed). My feeling, though, is that it is conceptually much simpler to back up cells in cells, rather than in other objects (especially comments, which you or the user may want to use for other purposes).

So, say I have `Sheet1` whose cells the user may change. I created this other sheet called `Sheet1_Mirror` (which you could create at `Workbook_Open` and could set to be hidden if you so desire -- up to you). To start with, the contents of `Sheet1_Mirror` would be identical to that of `Sheet1` (again, you could enforce this at `Workbook_Open`).

Every time `Sheet1`'s `Worksheet_Change` is triggered, the code checks whether the "changed" cell's value in `Sheet1` is actually different from that in `Sheet1_Mirror`. If so, it does the action you want and updates the mirror sheet. If not, then nothing.

This should put you on the right track:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Target.Cells
        'Has the value actually changed?
        If r.Value <> Sheet1_Mirror.Range(r.Address).Value Then
            'Yes it has. Do whatever needs to be done.
            MsgBox "Value of cell " & r.Address & " was changed. " & vbCrLf _
                & "Was: " & vbTab & Sheet1_Mirror.Range(r.Address).Value & vbCrLf _
                & "Is now: " & vbTab & r.Value
            'Mirror this new value.
            Sheet1_Mirror.Range(r.Address).Value = r.Value
        Else
            'It hasn't really changed. Do nothing.
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Francois.  I ended up going with this solution.

Comment: I tried it an get an error on line 5, If r.Value <> Sheet1_Mirror... Runtime 424, Object required..

Comment: Also tried: `Sheets("Sheet1_Mirror").Range(r.Address).Value` to no evail

Comment: I tested this code and it works. Did you try stepping through the code in debug mode? This will help you identify your error. Is `r` Nothing? Do you have a sheet called `Sheet1_Mirror`? Only you can find out...

Comment: The best, quick and error free method.  And the mirrored sheet you can always hide to not disturb the view.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.  When you enter a range it stores the original cell values in a dictionary object.  When the worksheet change is triggered it compares the stored values with the actuals and highlights any changes.
NB: to improve efficiency reference microsoft scripting runtime & replace the **As Object** with **As Scripting.Dictionary** and the **CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")** with **New Scripting.Dictionary**.

```
Option Explicit

Private previousRange As Object 'reference microsoft scripting runtime & use scripting.dictionary for better performance
                                'I've gone with late binding to avoid references from confusing the example


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Variant

    For Each cell In Target
        If previousRange.Exists(cell.Address) Then
            If previousRange.Item(cell.Address) <> cell.FormulaR1C1 Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Variant

    Set previousRange = Nothing 'not really needed but I like to kill off old references
    Set previousRange = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        previousRange.Add cell.Address, cell.FormulaR1C1
    Next

End Sub
```

ps. any vba code to update cells (even just colour) will stop excel's undo functionality from working!  To get around this you can reprogram undo functionality, but it can get quite memory intensive.  Sample solutions: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp / http://www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip23.htm

Answer (score 2):

This code uses Comments to store the prior value (Please note if you do need the comments for other purposes this method will remove them)

1. Cells that have no value have colour reset to `xlNone`
2. An intial value typed into a cell is blue (ColorIndex 34)
3. If the value is changed the cell goes from blue to yellow

[image]

**Normal module - turn display of comments off**

```
    Sub SetCom()
      Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlNoIndicator
    End Sub
```

**Sheet code to capture changes**

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim shCmt As Comment
    For Each rng1 In Target.Cells

    If Len(rng1.Value) = 0 Then
    rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    On Error Resume Next
    rng1.Comment.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Else

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shCmt = rng1.Comment
    On Error GoTo 0

    If shCmt Is Nothing Then
        Set shCmt = rng1.AddComment
        shCmt.Text Text:=CStr(rng1.Value)
         rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
    Else
        If shCmt.Text <> rng1.Value Then
            rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            shCmt.Text Text:=CStr(rng1.Value)
        End If
    End If
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I had exactly the same problem like this "Change cell A1 and the cell gets highlighted. That's what I'd expect. Double click B1 but don't change the value there and then click C1. You'll notice B1 gets highlighted! "

I didn't wanted to highlight a cell if it was only doubleclicked without value inside.

I solved in in easy way. Maybe it help somebody in future.

I've just added this on the beggining of the event:

```
 If Target.Value = "" Then
      Exit Sub
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this other thread that provides ways to captures the old value, so you can compare it with the "new" value and if those are then simply let it do nothing.

[How do I get the old value of a changed cell in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)