# VB - Excel checking previous value give an error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to learn a bit of VB and there is an exercise to change a value and check the previous value and if it is different do something. I eventually found a solution I could understand and get to work from : [How do I get the old value of a changed cell in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)  - solution 4. 
My code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Variant

    For Each cell In Target
        If previousRange.Exists(cell.Address) Then
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B12:B12")) Is Nothing Then
                If previousRange.Item(cell.Address) <> cell.FormulaR1C1 Then
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Variant

    Set previousRange = Nothing 'not really needed but I like to kill off old references
    Set previousRange = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        previousRange.Add cell.Address, cell.FormulaR1C1
    Next

End Sub
```

The next exercise was to add a button and perform an action depending on the user's response. So I added:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim currentValue, message As Integer

    currentValue = Range("C3").Value
    message = MsgBox("Click OK to add 1, cancel to leave", vbOKCancel, "Addition")

    If message = 1 Then
        Range("C3").Value = currentValue + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem I have is that the button adds one to C3 but then falls over at the `If previousRange.Exists(cell.Address)` statement on the `Worksheet_Change` sub. 
All the code is defined on Sheet1, but I do not seem to have a previous value generated for my button value(C3). How do I generate the previous value, or what am I missing?

Regards
J

As I seemed to have made things worse I have created a new spreadsheet with just the change events code and nothing else to try and simplify the problem. So the complete code I have now is:

```
Option Explicit
Dim previousRange As New Dictionary

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Variant

For Each cell In Target
    If previousRange.Exists(cell.Address) Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B12:B12")) Is Nothing Then
            If previousRange.Item(cell.Address) <> cell.FormulaR1C1 Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Variant

Set previousRange = Nothing 'not really needed but I like to kill off old references
Set previousRange = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each cell In Target.Cells
    previousRange.Add cell.Address, cell.FormulaR1C1
Next

End Sub
```

Now if I change the B12 cell, the `previousRange As New Dictionary` code is highlighted, and a message states "Compile error:User defined type not defined".
This code used to work before I introduced the message box and made a subsequent change. Must be user error. Can you help?

Regards J.

Answer (score 0):

The .Exists method is used on dictionary objects, like the example you've cited. But I don't see where you've declared a dictionary object in your code. Maybe you're missing a declaration statement for it?

```
Dim previousrange As New Dictionary
```

Please note that, like the solution you've cited, you'll need to declare this before the sub routine. Also, you'll need to enable the Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Here's how:

1. In the VBA editor, go to the **Tools** menu and click on **References...**
2. In the Available References list box, scroll down until you see **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**. Make sure its check box is checked.
3. Click **OK**.

Now you're able to use Dictionary objects.

Comment: Aaron, I think I have gone backward. I tried adding your code and I still got an error. Just incase I got it wrong i deleted what I had added (which is didn't recognise and included a comment) and tried again. I am now getting 'User-defined type not defined'. I am concerned I have delete the generic directory class and I am not sure how to add it back? J

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what's going on. Maybe you could add what you currently have, to the end of your original question? You can do this by editing your question.

Comment: Good deal - could you mark the answer as "answered" by clicking the check box below the voting? Thank you.