# Detecting what value was in a cell prior to a change

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

Is there a way to detect what a cell use to contain before it was changed.  I'm trying to perform actions based on what the previous value was in a cell.  I know there's Worksheet_Change but the Target it uses is the new value.

Comment: maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can undo the change, populate the undone value to a variable then redo the change like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim OldValue As Variant, NewValue As Variant
NewValue = Target.Value
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Undo
OldValue = Target.Value
Target.Value = NewValue
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox OldValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

We must **remember** what was in there.  Say cell **B9** was of interest.  In a *Standard Module* include the single line:

```
Public OldValue As Variant
```

and in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    v = Target.Value
    MsgBox v & vbCrLf & OldValue
    OldValue = v
End Sub
```