# Excel detecting and keeping track of (value) changes in any worksheet

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I've managed to write a code that detects value changes of particular cells in any worksheet, but I've struggled to construct something that detects and keeps track of ranged (value) changes.

For example, if a user decides to copy and paste some range of data (lets say more than 1 cell), it will not get caught by the macro. Same goes for a user selecting a range and then manually entering values into each cell while range is still selected.

My current code is constructed of 2 macros, the first runs anytime a worksheet selection change occurs and it stores the target.value into a previous value variable. The second macro runs anytime a worksheet change occurs and it tests if the targeted value is different than the previous one, if so it then notifies the user of the change that had occurred.

Comment: You should edit your post and add your code or what you've tried so far, otherwise you might not get help....

Comment: Look at the "related" questions down on the right below your question - lots of previous similar questions here (with answers)

Answer (score 2):

OK I don't really see anything here which covers the whole thing, so here's a rough attempt.

It will handle single or multi-cell updates (up to some limit you can set beyond which you don't want to go...)

It will not handle multi-area (non-contiguous) range updates, but could be extended to do so.

You likely should add some error handling also.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Where As String, OldValue As Variant, NewValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    Dim rngTrack As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Where = Target.Address
    NewValue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    OldValue = Target.Value 'get the previous values
    Target.Value = NewValue
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Set rngTrack = Sheets("Tracking").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    'multi-cell ranges are different from single-cell ranges
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 And Target.Cells.CountLarge < 1000 Then
        'multi-cell: treat as arrays
        For r = 1 To UBound(OldValue, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(OldValue, 2)
            If OldValue(r, c) <> NewValue(r, c) Then
                rngTrack.Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                  Array(Target.Cells(r, c).Address, OldValue(r, c), NewValue(r, c))
                Set rngTrack = rngTrack.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next c
        Next r
    Else
        'single-cell: not an array
        If OldValue <> NewValue Then
            rngTrack.Resize(1, 3).Value = _
              Array(Target.Cells(r, c).Address, OldValue, NewValue)
            Set rngTrack = rngTrack.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

"Undo" part to get the previous values is from Gary's Student's answer here:
[Using VBA how do I detect when any value in a worksheet changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513655/using-vba-how-do-i-detect-when-any-value-in-a-worksheet-changes?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is just what I was looking for. Is there any way of making this work on a higher - for example workbook level?
Thank you so much.

Kind regards, Domen

Comment: There is a `Workbook_SheetChange` event at the Workbook level. You could use very similar code there: just need to add tracking of the worksheet name, and exclude any sheets you don'r want tracked (such as the tracking sheet itself).

Comment: Is there any way to get past the selection return that happens while application.undo code goes through. Like if I write "5" into a blank cell and then click to another cell, (application.undo) will return my selection to the cell in which I changed the value, so to the cell where I wrote 5. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?
I thank you in advance for any wisdom you might share.

Kind regards

Comment: Before executing the undo, store the current selection: you can then restore it after the undo

Answer (score 1):

This subs will work for you but you have just implement codes in every sheet manually. Just need to copy paste. See below screenshot which is for 1 sheet `Sheet1`

[image]

(1) Declare a public variable.

```
Public ChangeTrac As Variant
```

(2) Write below codes in Worksheet_SelectionChange event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ChangeTrac = Target.Value
End Sub
```

(3) write below codes in Worksheet_Change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Cells()) Is Nothing Then
        If ChangeTrac <> Target.Value Then
            MsgBox "Value changed to Sheet1 " & Target.Address & " cell."
            Range(Target.Address).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Then test by changing data in any cell. It will prompt if any cell value is changed.

Comment: It actually returns me an error. (run-time error '13' type mismatch).And the problem that I had was detecting what occurred. What changed to what was my question, so I would have to store the previous value somewhere. It seems that excel has problems with storing values into ranges.

Comment: Would It help if I copy my code and film myself what to show you what I was searching for?

Comment: Better you share a sample workbook. Just upload the sample file to google drive and share link here.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?cid=47bc981d512cff00&page=view&resid=47BC981D512CFF00!774&parId=47BC981D512CFF00!136&app=Excel

As you can see this code keeps track of single cell changes. But if I decide I want to change "an area" or more than one cell at a time (for instance by copy - pasting,...), it doesn't detect and record that.

Comment: Code is like this:
Dim PreviousValue
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
logDate = Format(Now(), "dd/mmm/yyyy")
logTime = Format(Now(), " hh: mm: ss")
On Error Resume Next
If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address = "$A$1" And Range("A1") = "" Then
Else
  If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
    Sheets("Audit").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
 logDate & " " & logTime & ": " & Environ("Username") & " changed cell " & Target.Address & _
"     from " & PreviousValue & " to " & Target.Value & " in " & ActiveSheet.Name

  End If
  End If
 End Sub

Comment: Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target.Value
    
End Sub

Comment: It's much more complex to track multi-cell changes - that's why I suggested you review the previous times this has been asked here.

Comment: Mind linking me any such similar themes, I don't find any using "track multi-cell changes in excel stackoverflow".