# VBA - Change color of modified text

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that changes the color of the text in a cell if it is modified. However I was looking into something that only changes the color of modified text inside the cell. For example I have in cell A1 = "This cell" and when I change it to "This cell - this is new text" I would like just to change the color of "- this is new text"

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Else
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You can find answers here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the tip from Gary's Student, I retain the old value of cell and compare with the new value. Then use the lenght to get the 'difference' and color the 'characters'. Here's the modification:

```
Option Explicit
Public oldValue As Variant

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    oldValue = Target.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oldColor

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> oldValue Then
            oldColor = Target.Font.ColorIndex
            Target.Characters(Len(oldValue) + 1, Len(Target) - Len(oldValue)).Font.ColorIndex = IIf(oldColor = 3, 5, 3)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

P.S. Sorry my english

Comment: Thanks! It does work although if I change something in the beginning of the cell it will change the color of the characters on the right side. But anyway it does the purpose. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It is laborious:

1. detect that a cell has changed in the range of interest
2. use `UnDo` to get the original contents
3. use `ReDo` to get the new contents
4. compare them to get the changed characters
5. use the `Characters` property of the cell to format the new characters

I would use `UnDo` to avoid keeping a `static` copy of each of the 100 cells.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I put together:

```
Dim oldString$, newString$

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
    newString = Target.Value
        If Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Else
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Debug.Print "New text: " & newString
color_New_Text oldString, newString, Target
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        oldString$ = Target.Value
        Debug.Print "Original text: " & oldString$
    End If
End Sub

Sub color_New_Text(ByVal oldString As String, ByVal newString As String, ByVal theCell As Range)
Dim oldLen&, newLen&, i&, k&
oldLen = Len(oldString)
newLen = Len(newString)

Debug.Print newString & ", " & oldString
For i = 1 To newLen
    If Mid(newString, i, 1) <> Mid(oldString, i, 1) Then
        Debug.Print "different"
        Debug.Print theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
        If theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Else
            theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

It's two global variables, a `Worksheet_SelectionChange`and `Worksheet_Change`to get the strings.

Comment: The code is good.............. but may have trouble retaining the old values of all the cells in the range of interest with only one global.

Answer (score 1):

This will change the font, but it's not perfect.  Seems if you have different font colours in the same cell then `Target.Font.ColorIndex` returns NULL so it only works on the first change.

```
Option Explicit

Dim sOldValue As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sNewValue As String
    Dim sDifference As String
    Dim lStart As Long
    Dim lLength As Long
    Dim lColorIndex As Long

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        sNewValue = Target.Value
        sDifference = Replace(sNewValue, sOldValue, "")
        lStart = InStr(sNewValue, sDifference)
        lLength = Len(sDifference)
        If Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            lColorIndex = 5
        Else
            lColorIndex = 3
        End If
        Target.Characters(Start:=lStart, Length:=lLength).Font.ColorIndex = lColorIndex
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number
        'I haven't added error handling - trap any errors here.
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Sheet1.Worksheet_Change."
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        sOldValue = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:  It will only work with a continuous string.  Maybe can change to look at each character in `sOldValue` and `sNewValue` and change colour as required.

Comment: Looks good............should you not refresh `sOldValue` somewhere in the code ??

Comment: That's handled in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.  After the cell has been updated pressing enter will move to the next cell and capture the old value of that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim newvalue As String
    Dim olvalue As String
    Dim content
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Font.ColorIndex <> -4105 Or IsNull(Target.Font.ColorIndex) = True Then
            newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            oldvalue = Target.Value
            Content = InStr(newvalue, Replace(newvalue, oldvalue, ""))
            Target.Value = newvalue
            With Target.Characters(Start:=Content, Length:=Len(newvalue)).Font
                .Color = 5
            End With
        Else
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```