# capture multiple cell value before change event

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple values on cell ("F3:N3") that change dependent on user input on ("E18"). I am having trouble capturing the values before change. I would like the capture to happen on cells ("V8:AD8")
Below is the code..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = Range("E18").Address Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim sOldValue As String, sNewValue As String
    sNewValue = Target.Value

    Application.Undo

    Dim rOld As Range
     rOld = Range("F3:N3").Value

    Target.Value = sNewValue

    Range("V8:AD8").Value = rOld.Value

    Application.EnableEvents = True

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the old value of a changed cell in Excel VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Also, `rOld = Range("F3:N3").Value` isn't allowed since `rOld` is a range.

Comment: set rOld = Range("F3:N3"), move your code to worksheet_calculate

Comment: @kyle so how would i change rOld to make it work

Comment: @Nathan_Sav i set rOld = Range("F3:N3") but why would i need to move my code to worksheet_calculale

Comment: Because you said that changing on cell affects others, so they will be changed on calculate, I am not sure when the change event is triggered.  You can leave it in the change though, i'll have a look at what's going on.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav input/change happens on the E18 so that's where the traget is? Values I want to capture are on F3-N3 and want to display them on V8-AD8