# When using Worksheet_Change - how can I get the value in a cell before change?

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel sheet, I have a range "plot" that triggers a sub-routine upon change. I used the following code for that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("plot").Address Then
        auto_save_data (current_plot) ' <- doesn't work
        restore_data
    End If
End Sub
```

This code has to first save the data from the current worksheet to a specific range, that defined by `current_plot` in another worksheet (let's call it "DATA"), by calling `auto_save_data (current_plot)`.
Then it restores the data from a specific range in "DATA" that is defined by `Range("plot")`, by calling `restore_data`.

The `restore_data` sub-routine above work as expected, but `auto_save_data` doesn't. The problem is that when the user change the value of "plot" I need to somehow know what was the value before the change, so I can save the data to the correct place before restoring the data from "DATA" for the value after update, and by that deleting the data in the current sheet.

I tried to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim current_plot As Variant
    If Target.Address = Range("plot").Address Then
        current_plot = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

But it has 2 problems:

1. It didn't work. The sub-routine `Worksheet_Change` didn't seem to recognize the value of the variable `current_plot`, albeit, it didn't throw an error.
2. I tried another method from [the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba), that save the old value to a hidden sheet. That worked, except when the user changes the value in "plot" without selecting another range first (then the value in the hidden sheet does not update).

So my question is: **What is the simplest method** (I'm very new to VBA) **to use the value that was in `Target` before the routine `Worksheet_Change` was triggered?**

**EDIT:** I changed "plot" to be a single cell range ($P$2), to focus the question on the real problem.

Comment: I think you simply failed to give `current_plot` module-level scope, because you placed  `Dim current_plot As Variant` inside the `SelectionChange` subroutine instead of at the beginning of the module.  But try using [the `Undo` method from that page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7035579/6535336) as well - it should be robust enough to do what you want.

Comment: Is `Range("plot")` a single cell? You are comparing it to Target in a way that infers it is a single cell.

Comment: `' "$P$2:$R$2" is the range of "plot"`

Comment: Without an `application.enableevents = false` it seems like you would be in an infinite loop.

Comment: `If Target.Address = Range("plot").Address Then` This should be `If not intersect(target,Range("plot")) then`. You may also want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)

Comment: @YowE3K Both `SelectionChange` and `Cange` are in the same worksheet.

Comment: @EBH With `Dim current_plot As Variant` inside one of the subroutines, the variable is local to that subroutine.  Moving the declaration to the beginning of the module (prior to the first `Sub`) makes it module-level in scope and therefore accessible to both subroutines.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for that! Now problem 1 is solved.

Comment: @Jeeped I have edited the question to resolve the range issue. As for the infinite loop - well, that didn't happen.

Comment: So what is problem two?  (And why haven't we closed the question as "too broad" if there is more than one problem per question?!? ;) )

Comment: Problem 2 says: _"That worked, except when the user changes the value in "plot" without selecting another range first."_ It's all part of the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "Plot" is a single-cell range in the worksheet which has `Name` of "DATA", place the following code in the code module of `Worksheets("DATA")`:

```
'Declare a variable with global scope, i.e. accessible in this worksheet
'and in other code modules.
Public current_plot As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("plot").Address Then
        'Use "current_plot" whenever the cell is changed
        MsgBox "Old value: " & current_plot & vbCrLf & _
               "New value: " & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("plot").Address Then
        'Update "current_plot" whenever the cell is selected
        current_plot = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

and place this code in the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Initialise "current_plot" when the workbook is opened
    Worksheets("DATA").current_plot = Worksheets("DATA").Range("Plot").Value
End Sub
```

---

Assuming you don't want to know what used to be in the cell, but instead you actually want to know what was in the cell the last time you made use of the cell's value, you can simplify this a bit by using the following:

```
'Declare a variable with global scope, i.e. accessible in this worksheet
'and in other code modules.
Public current_plot As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("plot").Address Then
        'Use "current_plot" whenever the cell is changed
        MsgBox "Old value: " & current_plot & vbCrLf & _
               "New value: " & Target.Value

        '...
        '... process whatever needs to be processed
        '...

        'Save the value we used this time
        current_plot = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

and place this code in the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Initialise "current_plot" when the workbook is opened
    Worksheets("DATA").current_plot = Worksheets("DATA").Range("Plot").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure what the MsgBox is for, but this works good as long as you leave the rage "plot" between changes, otherwise `current_plot` does not update.

Comment: (a) The message box was only to show that you could access the old and new values.  (b) If you don't leave the cell between "changes" what do you want the "old" value to be - the value before they started making changes, or the value after they made a change to an incorrect value but before correcting it to a valid value?  E.g. If the value was `5`, then they changed it to `"xyz"`, then changed it to `6`, what value do you want as the value stored in `current_plot` - the `5` or the `"xyz"`?  (If you want `"xyz"` then just set `current_plot` as part of the `Change` event.)

Comment: It's not about incorrect values. "plot" is a cell that limited to a list of values, that the user choose from. Let's say he is now in plot `100`, and want to change to plot `200`, and then go back to `100`. While doing that all the data that he entered in other places in the sheet ("Input") has to be saved (in some other sheet - "DATA") and replaced by the data that is already in "DATA" for plot `200`, and then again to be reversed to the data saved for `100`. ...

Comment: ...  If he selects some other cell then "plot" in between, (i.e. after the last change to `200` he leaves the cell, then choose it again and change it to `100`) that's work fine. But, if **immediately after changing to `200` he changes it back to `100`, then the value of `current_plot` stays `100`, and all the data for plot `200` is saved in `100` area. I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: @EBH - if the user is changing the cell from `100` to `200` and then perhaps to `300` (or `100` again) and you want to save the `200` once they have set it to that, then just set `current_plot` as part of the `Change` event - i.e. `current_plot = Target.Value`.  I.e. every time you believe that the cell contains something you want to save for future use, save it for future use.

Comment: WOW! that was what I'm looking for, so simple and clear. I am so confused by the VBA syntax that I couldn't see this simple solution before. Thanks a million for the patience and all the help!