# Get the old value in a Worksheet_Change Target

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have an Excelsheet with 2 columns. The second column must only
contain values which are also in the first column.
If a value in the first column changes I have to replace all its
occurrences in the second column.
There is a Worksheet_Change event which is called if a worksheet changes but unfortunately I can't find a way to get the old value of a changed cell.

Is it possible to find out the old value of a cell?

Comment: What's your code doing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found [get the old value in a worksheet change target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba). The selection_change event is mentioned there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I read your question wrong, here's to get your old value before selection change

```
Dim oldValue As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Do whatever you need to do.
End Sub
```

Comment: Now we're talking! OP might need to perhaps verify the `Target` column in `SelectionChange`, but that's a good start; capture the old value *before* it's modified. Given how much effort OP put in their question, I think that's more than good enough to earn a vote.