# Excel autosave when cell value is increases by 1

Tags: excel, autosave, vba

I am trying to create a macro that auto-saves my excel workbook whenever the value in a specific cell increases by 1.

I have the code for the auto-save whenever the cell changes which I will post below;

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I can't seem to adapt the code for the macro to only execute when the value in the cell increases by one. I.e, cell value is 10, only save workbook when the cell value is 11 and so forth.

Thank you.

Edit: 
The problem has been solved. If anyone is looking for the solution check this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1265717/excel-auto-save-macro

Comment: You probably need a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` even too, to see when a selection is changed. However, is the cell value a value, or the result of a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Worksheet_SelectionChange** to get old value of cell ([Binils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487242/binil)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4668410/5778170)), then do appropriate comparison (newval - oldval = 1).

Comment: Thanks @pnuts , changed answer a little bit.

Comment: I didn't fully utilize this but it did help me reach the final solution. If anyone needs it it's mentioned above. Thank you again, I selected your answer as a solution.