# Worksheet_change: i do not want it to activate when value in cell does not change

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I am using worksheet_change to automatically change cell colours when a user makes any changes to a cell's value. However, my `else` clause runs when a user enters and leaves a cell without changing the cell's value (User probably double clicked a cell, then clicked on a different cell instead of pressing escape.) . How can I amend my code so that the `Else` clause only runs if the user has made changes to the cell's value?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z200")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then

Exit Sub

Else

Range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

End If
```

Comment: You could get the old value before the change and compare it with the new value -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the old value of a changed cell in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You either have to:

1. Educate users to push Escape rather than Enter if they have gone
   into Edit mode but have changed their mind; or
2. Make a copy of the range, check the value against the copy and if
   they've made changes, update the copy with the new value and change
   the original cell color.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try...

```
Dim oVal
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z200")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target <> oVal Then
        Range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        oVal = Target
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z200")) Is Nothing Then
    oVal = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```