# Previous value in cell

Tags: vba

I have two columns,

1. "**Date**" (Column **H**)
2. "**Previous Date in Cell**" (Column **I**)

I would like to use VBA to automatically keep the previous value of "Date" (Column H) and save the value before change in "Previous Date in Cell" (Column I).

Ex. If **H2** = **01-06-2018** and the values is changed to **02-06-2018**, **I2** should than show **01-06-2018** as it is the previous value of the cell.

I would like this code to work for a whole column of cells, not just a single cell. The values in columns **H** is not manually updated it comes from a formula that looks at a SQL pull out from a third party system. A lot of cells in columns **H** can therefore be changed simultaneously.

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim newVal As Variant
If Target.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Intersect(Range("H:H"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
newVal = Target.Value
Application.Undo
Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value
Target.Value = newVal
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post your code?

Comment: Use: [Worksheet.Change Event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff839775(v=office.14))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the old value of a changed cell in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private varPrev As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 8 Then
        varPrev = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 8 Then
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Value = varPrev
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried wholsheet_SelectionChange before but it only works when I manually change the value in a cell. I'll post my code here so far here. But again is aslo only working when I manually change the value in the cell.

Comment: Is it possible some how to always check if the values is changed (Not manually) and the put the old value in column I. Or can the code check for changes when my SQL table is updates?