# VBA Changing A Value, to Call a Macro. Ignore

Tags: excel, vba, function

Hello Stack Overflow Community! I am a major Noob at VBA scripting and think I have an easy question? I have some simple code on my worksheet that calls a function every time a value is changed in a specific cell.

The Problem is, is that cell is a drop down menu and when you change the selection of the drop down to the same value it still runs the code..

To be clear, I want the code to run when the drop down changes. Just not when it "changes" to the same value. Pasting my code below. Let me know if you can help!

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$W$21" Then
        Call Financing
    End If
End Sub
```

---

I was thinking maybe add a .ignore or something maybe?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a static value of the previous value and compare before launching the Financing sub procedure.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    static oldW1  as variant
    If Target.Address = "$W$21" Then
        if target.value <> oldW1 then
            oldW1 = Target.value
            Call Financing
        end if
    End If
End Sub
```

Static vars are 'remembered' by the sub procedure or function where they are declared. Normally, oldW1  would be 'forgotten' (and destructed) when the Worksheet_Change was completed and exited. However, with a static oldW1, the second time (and all subsequent times) the Worksheet_Change is entered it 'remembers' what the value of oldW1 was the last time it was used.

This does not mean that a static var is globally public; it is only available within the function or sub procedure where it was declared.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly. Still a little confused on how that works but it does!

Comment: Added a diatribe about static vars.