# How to capture a cell value in Excel when a cell updated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in Excel that gets updated on basis of RAND() function.
Each time I update the cell, I want to capture the previous values in a separate column. So that I can compute mean later on.

How to achieve this??

Comment: You could look into `Worksheet_Calculate()` and go from there.

Comment: Why go through the cell value? Why not write the rnd value into a variable as well?

Comment: can u show how?

Comment: Take a look at this [SO Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Copy below into Worksheet module and change "A1" cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing) Then
    i = i + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Recalculation of a function doesn't trigger a Worksheet_Change event.