# Execute code if the value entered in the cell is not the same as the previous value

Tags: excel, vba

I have data validation as list for some cells (possible values are "Enrolled", "Waitlisted", "Cancelled"). I need to execute some code if the value of these cells changes, only if the new value is not the same as the existing one. Question is, how can I get Excel to compare the previous value of the cell with the current one.

I tried this solution ([How do I get the old value of a changed cell in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)) but it didn't work. What am I missing? Here is some sample code. Currently, it changes the cell colors even if I enter the same value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim previous_value As String

previous_value = oval

Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "enrolled"
        If previous_value = Target.Value Then
        MsgBox "you entered the same value"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        Else 
        Target.Interior.Color = vbBlue

        End If
    Case Is = "waitlisted"
' (....etc.)
End Select


End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim oval As String

If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    oval = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I checked the other answer you listed compared to yours. You need to have your variables outside of the macros but within the sheet so they can be stored for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use something like this below code, you can save the most recent clicked instance in a named range and then check it against whatever the user entered. Obviously, this goes in the respective sheet code.

```
Private anOldValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    If Target.Value = anOldValue Then

        MsgBox "Same value!"
    End If
End If

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    anOldValue = Target.Value

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @PGCodeRider! I can't seem to be able to adapt your solution for what I'm trying to achieve. 1) I am trying to prevent the user from selecting by mistake the same value from the drop-down 2) but if they select one of the two other possible values, some other code needs to run. This solution only accomplishes item 1. It didn't work when I tried to use it within each case of the Select case statements. Nor I can use Else If statements (If target.value = "waitlisted etc.), because I don't know which 2 out of 3 possible values I need to check for. I don't know if that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code. Thanks @PGCodeRider for the help!

```
Private anOldValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "enrolled"
            If Target.Value = anOldValue Then
               MsgBox "Student already enrolled!"
            Else 'code that needs to happen when "enrolled" is selected
               Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        Case Is = "waitlisted"
            If Target.Value = anOldValue Then
                MsgBox "Student already waitlisted!"
            Else  'code that needs to happen when "waitlisted" is selected
               Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
            End If

        Case Is = "cancelled"
            If Target.Value = anOldValue Then
                MsgBox "Student already cancelled!"
            Else   'code that needs to happen when "cancelled" is selected
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 30

            End If
    End Select
End If

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    anOldValue = Target.Value

End If

End Sub
```