# Excel formula to return cell when not match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Look in the first Image, Row 10 having value 0.096 now see the formula bar 
**`=+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Stirupps",B106,2)),IF(C106=8,0.075,(C106*8)/1000),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Link",B106,1)),(C106*10)/1000,))`**

[image]

Let's start with

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Stirupps",B106,2))
```

Search

> ("Stirupps",in cell B106 , Start pos)

This will return True

now **ISNUMBER** Func will convert it to 1

> `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Stirupps",B106,2))` Logical Expression

True

> `IF(C106=8,0.075,(C106*8)/1000)`

False

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Link",B106,1)),(C106*10)/1000,))
```

Again Search

```
Search("Link",in cell B106, Start pos)
```

If True

```
(C106*10)/1000,)
```

If False

```
`))`
```

Now when I paste this formula in cell H16, look the Second Image

[image]

It will search the Strings in Cell B16 which doesn't match. It will return nothing

**Now my question**

How can it return the earlier value, when the cell does not contain the string "Stirrups" and "Link".

I want the value to remain unaffected in cell H16.

Comment: You don't have entered `ELSE`-cases for thesecond and third `IF`. Which value do you want to retain?

Comment: There is not directly way in IF condition but there is a way with coding VBA in `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event. look this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba

Comment: @ OverflowStacker The value in second image Cell H16