# Detect cell value has changed VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to detect with the `Workbook_SheetChange` that the value of a cell has changed.

This event triggers also when double-clicking any cell. I want to avoid this case because when doing that, the cell has not really changed until you type a new value.

There is any way to avoid this case inside that event?

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)`  Trap it before?

Comment: Try this: https://www.toolbox.com/tech/programming/question/cell-change-event-in-vba-091409/

Comment: You can check that using 'Change` event, too. It will only fill a variable value to compare the previous `Target` one.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, copy the next two events and a `Private` variable in the sheet code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private PrevVal As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If CStr(Target.Value) = PrevVal Then Exit Sub
   Debug.Print "Changed..."
   'your code in case of a real change...
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    PrevVal = CStr(Target.Value)
End Sub
```

The `SelectionChange` event will place the selected cell value in `PrevVal` variable, which will be used to compare the previous value with the 'resulted' one in `Change` event.

It will not treat the cases of multiple cells selection. In some circumstances, the previous value(s) is not possible to be memorized. When a multiple cells range is copied over an existing range, selecting only one cell...

It can be adapted to treat this case, only if **the exact range to be overwritten by the pasting to previously be selected**.

Comment: @Enrique González Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it solve your problem?

Comment: I have tried and the event SelectionChange is never called, I do not know why, events are enabled for sure. Could it be Excel version? I am using Excel 2016.

I

Comment: @Enrique González Do you mean that all the other events are triggered, except `SelectionChange`? This cannot be possible in any version... If you have other active events and used `Application.EnableEvents = False`, followed by `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the code end and an error occurs between the two line, the events could remain not enabled. Please, run a single code line in a testing sub:  `Application.EnableEvents = True` and play with events after that...

Comment: I have solve it using Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick,  i do not know why but Worksheet_SelectionChange or Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick was not triggering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` & `Worksheet_Change` to check if the cell value has really changed or it was simply double-clicked without any change

```
Option Explicit

Private oldValue As String

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Value <> oldValue Then
      MsgBox "Value is Updated"
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The event BeforeDoubleClick does not trigger, i do not know why

Comment: You need to place the code inside the Worksheet module. Not as a custom module.