# Is is possible to run a macro in excel when the value of the cell is changing instead to wait until it i changed?

Tags: excel, vba

When I change the value of a cell in excel, I would like to put the actual value of the cell in another cell and put the new value in the cell.

The code would you be something like that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$EC$1" Then


    Range("C1").Value = Range("E1").Value
    
End If

End Sub
```

This macro is executed when the cell has the new value, so I don't have access to the actual value to can pass to the other cell. I know that because I set a breakpoint in the code.

So I am wondering if exists a macro that is fired when the actual value is changing, to can set the actual value to another cell.

Thanks.

Comment: In the Selection_Change event like [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668523/19353309) you store the old value of E1/EC1 (whatever it is supposed to be in your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event that runs before or during a cell change. However, if you want to get the old cell value, you can use `Application.Undo` to get the old value and then restore the new value. Something like this (code is commented for your understanding; in this case, all cells in column E are being monitored and the 'old values' are put into the cell in the same row of column C ... obviously you can change this for your needs):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' only do this if a single cell has been changed in, for example, column E
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 5 Then
        Dim vaOld As Variant, vaNew As Variant, rngSel As Range
        ' must switch off events otherwise we will end up in an infinite loop
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ' store the new (ie just entered) value
        vaNew = Target.value
        If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Set rngSel = Selection
        ' get the old (ie previous) value
        Application.Undo
        vaOld = Target.value
        ' put the old value in, for example, column C
        Target.Offset(0, -2).value = vaOld
        ' restore the new value
        Target.value = vaNew
        ' tidy up
        If Not rngSel Is Nothing Then rngSel.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The code assumes, for example, there are no merged cells involved.