# Saving a Cell's Previous Value in Another Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a data entry sheet (not shown) and another sheet that pulls information for specific items for weekly reports (shown) that need to be submitted. The quantities in Columns J and L refence totals in other areas and as a result, the values change. What I'm looking to do is record the previous values in J:J to K:K and the previous values in L:L to M:M if they change with data entry. I've scoured the internet, but have not come across a solution that works for me. I'm assuming it's going to required VBA but I'm not opposed to other methods.

[image: Visual]

Comment: Look for solutions using the `Worksheet.Calculate` event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the old value of a changed cell in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I tried Calculate event and could not find a way to grab old cell values, only new. Same for Change event. Maybe you can find something useful in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba

Comment: Copy the `J` values to e.g. column `A` of a hidden sheet. The Calculate event code needs to read the `J` values and the `A` values into arrays. Then it loops through the rows of the arrays and if the values in the same row are different, the `A` value is written to column `K`. Finally, if there were any differences (implement a boolean), the `J` array is written to the `A` column. Do the same for the `L` column.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Calculate: Backup Previous Values

- It will add a very hidden sheet to store the current `J` and `L` column values in the hidden sheet's columns `A` and `B` respectively.
- You don't have to run anything, it runs automatically. Just copy the codes to the two correct places.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    BackupPreviousValues Me, "J3", "K", "A2"
    BackupPreviousValues Me, "L3", "M", "B2"
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub BackupPreviousValues( _
        ByVal sws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal SrcAddress As String, _
        ByVal DstColumn As String, _
        ByVal BkpAddress As String)

    Const HIDDEN_DATA_NAME As String = "HiddenData"

    Dim scrg As Range
    
    With sws.Range(SrcAddress)
        Set scrg = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(scrg, sws.UsedRange)
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = GetSingleColumnRange(srg)
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DstColumn)
    Dim dData() As Variant: dData = GetSingleColumnRange(drg)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = sws.Parent
    Dim hws As Worksheet: Set hws = GetHiddenWorksheet(wb, HIDDEN_DATA_NAME)
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = hws.Range(BkpAddress).Resize(rCount)
    Dim hData() As Variant: hData = GetSingleColumnRange(hrg)
     
    Dim r As Long, IsDifferenceFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If StrComp(CStr(sData(r, 1)), CStr(hData(r, 1)), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            dData(r, 1) = hData(r, 1)
            IsDifferenceFound = True
        End If
    Next r
     
    If IsDifferenceFound Then
        hrg.Value = sData ' backup (new)
        drg.Value = dData ' result (old)
    End If
    
End Sub
```

```vb
Function GetSingleColumnRange( _
    ByVal crg As Range) _
As Variant
    Dim Data() As Variant
    If crg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = crg.Value
    Else
        Data = crg.Value
    End If
    GetSingleColumnRange = Data
End Function
```

```vb
Function GetHiddenWorksheet( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal SheetName As String) _
As Worksheet
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = SheetName
    End If
    
    If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Set GetHiddenWorksheet = ws

End Function
```

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Just getting back to work and giving your code a try. I'm getting a Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined in the sheet module. It highlights "Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate () in yellow and "BackupPreviousValues" in blue. Not sure if the version of Excel matters and I probably should have included it in my original question, but I'm running Excel365.