How to copy Active cell when cell value changes
I need to automate some entries. I have the formula below that creates a message box when anything in column A:A changes:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Check if the changed cell is A1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Run your macro here
        Call MyMacro
    End If
End Sub
Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "Cell has changed!"
End Sub

I need the macro to store the value that has changed, so it can go to a different tab and perform a search function. I haven't programmed in a while - how do I store that value since technically, if i press enter after entering the data or click on a different cell, my active cell has changed and I cant just copy the "ActiveCell".

Target  is a range and holds the cell information that triggered it.  So myVal = Target.Value?

@ScottCraner - Target.Value will be the new value. Sounds like the OP wants the original value

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba

@CHill60 hmmm, I can read it both ways, so you may be correct.  That is probably something we need clarification on.  either way the comments should give the OP a path forward.

Hi - thank you both!  I want the new value (?) - so for example, if in Column A:A, in Cell A55, I enter "EID13", and either click enter or click out of the cell - I want "E13" to be stored in a string.

What's the rule for the transformation EID13 >> E13  ?

Typo on my part - E13 was intended to be EID13 - but I tested out "Target.Value" - and that worked. Thank you!
